# Wrong shape of confusion matrix returned by tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I'm using the [a bit modified] code from Simple Audio Recognition tutorial from tensorflow ( https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition ) on my own data. Here's the error message at checkpoint:

```
`File "train.py", line 446, in <module>
tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))`
`File "train.py", line 265, in main
total_conf_matrix += conf_matrix
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (77,77) 
(76,76) (77,77)`
```

It appears that the shape of conf_matrix does not coincide with total_conf_matrix. How could that be? It may be difficult which column and row is missing because I'm working on quite big dataset. Any suggestions how to deal with it without adding some blank rows or catching an exception and ignoring error?